# Open password protected video file in android VideoView

Tags: android, video, encryption

I am working on a prototype, which include some video files in various formats. All these files need to be protected against unauthorized access.

1. First i tried to use encryption decryption, means file will be stored in encrypted format and before opening file I will decrypt file in cache, but problem with that it takes too much time for a video file to be decrypted before playing.
2. Then i tried libmedia library to reduce this decryption time, but problem with that it is not free secondly it requires Internet on Android device and third it involves some streaming server.
3. Now I am trying to enforce content security by making video files password protected, but not able to find any solution to view password protected VideoFile using Android code.

Any one have any idea about solution.